# Unusual Php syntax in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I saw an interesting syntax in symfony 2.x and i am not sure how to call it and what type of variable it is.

In the view, There is a helper variable called `$view` and it can be used in for many things and here is what i don't understand

Sometimes it is used like an array:

```
$view['action']->someMethod();
```

and other times it is used as an object

```
$view->generateUrl(...);
```

Both in the same file. Dumping variables using `var_dump()` in symfony is not a very good idea .

So What kind of object is this, and how can I create it.

Comment: [`ArrayAccess`](http://us.php.net/ArrayAccess) interface can be used to allow array-ish access to objects.

Comment: Maybe post this ^ as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ArrayAccess you can access to the object as array with associative keys

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php